# Capture image without intent, Gives different output on different devices

Tags: android, android-camera

My requirement is neither to display camera preview nor to use camera intent for image capture.

There for I find a way which is working for my first testing device (Galaxy tab 7").

My `CaptureImage` function is as below

```
private void CaptureImage() {
        int FrontCameraFound = getCameraID();
        if (FrontCameraFound != -1) {
            mCamera = Camera.open(FrontCameraFound);

            parameters = mCamera.getParameters();

            mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
            mCamera.startPreview();

            Camera.PictureCallback mCall = new Camera.PictureCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {

                    bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);

                    // set bitmap tp image view just to check 
                    // if image capture proper, testing purpose
                    iv_image.setImageBitmap(bmp);

                    mCamera.stopPreview();
                    mCamera.release();
                    mCamera = null;
                }
            };
            mCamera.takePicture(null, null, mCall);
        }
    }
```

and `getCameraID` function as below

```
private int getCameraID() {
    Camera.CameraInfo cameraInfo = new Camera.CameraInfo();

    for (int camIdx = 0; camIdx < Camera.getNumberOfCameras(); camIdx++) {
        Camera.getCameraInfo(camIdx, cameraInfo);
        // for capture image from back camera
        // If want to capture from front 
        // then change it to CAMERA_FACING_FRONT
        if (cameraInfo.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK) {
            try {
                return camIdx;
            } catch (RuntimeException e) {

            }
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Now I am facing difficulty to run successfully above code on different devices.

- Samsung Galaxy S+ (2.3.6) : Front camera always return green image but coding for Back camera working fine.
- Samsung Galaxy Nexus (4.1) : coding doesn't work Neither for Front nor for Back camera & gives "takePicture" failed.
- LG Optimus Net (2.3.4) : only back camera is there & working fine.
- Samsung Galaxy Tab 7 " (2.3.3) : both camera working fine.
- Motorola Xoom (3.1) : both camera working fine.

Logcat of Samsung Galaxy Nexus :

```
09-21 09:37:42.125: E/AndroidRuntime(4647): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: takePicture failed
09-21 09:37:42.125: E/AndroidRuntime(4647):     at android.hardware.Camera.native_takePicture(Native Method)
09-21 09:37:42.125: E/AndroidRuntime(4647):     at android.hardware.Camera.takePicture(Camera.java:1061)
09-21 09:37:42.125: E/AndroidRuntime(4647):     at android.hardware.Camera.takePicture(Camera.java:1006)
09-21 09:37:42.125: E/AndroidRuntime(4647):     at fortyonepost.com.pwop.TakePictureDemoActivity.CaptureImage(TakePictureDemoActivity.java:63)
09-21 09:37:42.125: E/AndroidRuntime(4647):     at fortyonepost.com.pwop.TakePictureDemoActivity.onCreate(TakePictureDemoActivity.java:36)
09-21 09:37:42.125: E/AndroidRuntime(4647):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
09-21 09:37:42.125: E/AndroidRuntime(4647):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
09-21 09:37:42.125: E/AndroidRuntime(4647):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
```

It is not possible to check code for every devices , I just test my code on 5 devices and 2 device causes problem, so is there any standard way to fetch image from camera without intent & preview.

Please note that I include  in manifest & set minimum sdk version to 9

**Update :**
In 4.1 Nexus Galaxy `takePicture Failed` from Line number 1061 in Camera.java class, here is the [class link](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/hardware/Camera.java#L1061) which gives me information that `native_takePicture(msgType); function in Camera.java` did throw that

Comment: i want to capture image from camera without knowing to user, and must be compatible to all device having API level 9+, as i mention in some device it work fine but for some device that is not working as mention in question

Comment: In your logcat on Galaxy Nexus, the `takePicture()` method is shown to be called from `onCreate()`, not from your `CaptureImage()` method. Is this correct?

Comment: Sorry, previously i named of CaptureImage function was surfaceChanged previously. I edited logcat

Comment: Without displaying camera preview and camera intent, how can you have captured image? Yes "Do you want to capture image of your phone screen"?

Comment: no i don't want to capture phone screen, as i mention above code is working fine in Xoom, Galaxy tab, LG net,HTC wildfire without displaying preview to user or without using camera intent, but for two device i encounter problems

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After several search, i found that preview of camera is necessary and i wonder how my code works well in some devices even it is faulty.

Any ways solution is that,

We require camera preview hold on surface view and we can hide that surface view behind any other view, I take surface view in framelayout(i know it is deprecated) and above it i take image view, for surface view i just take 80*80 dp surface view because small surface view like 30*30 dp didn't work and again through error.

Answer (score 3):

Camera handling in android devices is major PITA -  different devices ( and even android versions on same device)  can and certainly will behave differently.  Basically you are speaking with some demon process  on device, and they are different from  each other.

I do not have solution for all problems,  but here are my findings so far

- not all resolutions are working properly,  even it they are advertised in camera parameters.  You have to  test them while setting up camera in case there are problems
- preview data come to you via mmapped memory region
- NV21 format is always supplied and shall be default,   but I would query camera settings.  When you open camera, it can have some settings from other application which used camera just before. ( it is said nowhere that camera will be reset to defaults when you open it )

I have developed some camera management stuff developed for  JavaOCR Project,  and it kind of works on most devices. Feel free to use this as inspiration:

http://sourceforge.net/p/javaocr/code/240/tree/trunk/demos/camera-utils/src/main/java/net/sf/javaocr/demos/android/utils/camera/CameraManager.java

Comment: a very silly question : is it necessary to display preview through surface or surface texture ?? because without preview i am not able to capture image in 4.1, BTW thank's for sharing code, i will look up to that

Comment: documentation says that it is necessary to pass fully configured surface view and start preview in order to take a picture. However, nothing requires that surface view is on front and visible.  See: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html

Comment: So do you want to say that if we kept surface as invisible than this problem will get solved , am i right ?

Comment: I can not promiss that your problem will be solved by this. But keep in mnd that decodeBitmap() awaits compressed bitmap data,  and pictureCalback() dies not necessarily delievers proper compressed format to you. You wull have to check (or adjust) camera configuration to match those formats and decode it correctly

Comment: i don't face problems in fetching bitmap from bytes, and i tried to set invisible to surface but no luck still.

Comment: Your first comment helped me to find solution, I take framelayout in that i hide surface behind imageView, after that i capture image with camera.setPreviewDisplay(SurfaceHolder), camera.startPreview() & camera.takePicture, only one minus point is that, we require layout visibility.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the Camera.setOneShotPreviewCallback method and then process the image

Try using YuvImage and compress it before passing it to the bitmapfactory, like so:

```
YuvImage yuvimage = new YuvImage(byteArr, ImageFormat.NV21, width, height, null);
    Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, width, height);
    ByteArrayOutputStream outstr = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    yuvimage.compressToJpeg(rect, 100, outstr);
    Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(outstr.toByteArray(), 0, outstr.size());
```

EDIT:

You must use a surface view but the surface view can be hidden below another view so it's not visible on screen but still exists and active.

Comment: Thanks Tomas for answer but my main problem is that when takePicture function called it and immediately it failed so onPictureTaken not called

Comment: Try using the setOneShotPreviewCallback(previewCallback) method of the Camera object instead of takePicture.

Comment: but how can preview callback will execute without having preview ??

Comment: Like stated in comments of Konstantin Pribluda answer, you must have a surface view and it can't be set to invisible BUT you can use a small (1X1 pixel) surface view and put another view above it, the result is a surface which is invisible to the user which I presume is what you want.